# ipcalc - why it can't give correct network size by default

Tags: networking, ipv4, cidr

I found `ipcalc` didn't give correct network size when not specify the netmask,

In below result, it take the hosts count as 254, but not 2^24 -2,

```
eric@ePc:~$ ipcalc 101.12.12.12

Address:   101.12.12.12         01100101.00001100.00001100. 00001100
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   101.12.12.0/24       01100101.00001100.00001100. 00000000
HostMin:   101.12.12.1          01100101.00001100.00001100. 00000001
HostMax:   101.12.12.254        01100101.00001100.00001100. 11111110
Broadcast: 101.12.12.255        01100101.00001100.00001100. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class A
```

But, if I give netmask by hand `ipcalc 101.12.12.12/8`, then it gives correct result.

I want to know: did ipcalc do this not properly? Or, ipv4 address are used in this way in real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

classless inter domain routing was invented last century, since then it has not been practical to derive a netmask from a network address,

101.0.0.0 used to be a class A network, I don't know if it still is, neither does ipcalc.

Comment: If it don't know, shouldn't it assume the address as class A by default?

Comment: No, address classes don't exist anymore. They were deprecated more than 20 years ago...

Comment: @Eric-Wang  for a start you didn't write it as a class A address. 101.12.12.12 as a address is 101.789516, and a few applications will still accept IP addresses in that form, ipcalc isn't one of them. telnet OTOH does.

Comment: @SanderSteffann That shocks me ... I still saw ipv4 class in wiki pages.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately lots of training material (including that from the big vendors) is severely outdated... They still teach networking like addresses are classful and IPv6 is something new and experimental.